# Can I run a different workflow for develop merges into master with CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

My `.circleci/config.yml` is:

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:8.11.1

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run:
          command: yarn test
          environment:
            SOME: 'stuff'
```

This works well with github currently for my feature branches PR'ed against `develop`. I want to set up another workflow for when I have a PR of `develop` into `master`. I want to trigger the `yarn integration` script with different environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to see the target/base branch of PR from within CircleCI. You'd need to create a GitHub personal token and do some scripting with their API in order to accomplish this.